# <faultcode xmlns:a="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">a:InvalidSecurity</faultcode>

Tags: web-services, wcf

The Web Service is hosted on the server which has no internet connection

I'm using SOAPUI to access the web service url and test

but getting the following error information any help really appreciated

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <faultcode xmlns:a="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">a:InvalidSecurity</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">An error occurred when verifying security for the message.</faultstring>
      </s:Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

is it possible to copy the "oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" file in to local server and access , if so any body can pl list out the steps to fallow.

Comment: I think the problem is with the SSL certificate serving the domain. Check it with chrome or firefox.

Answer (score 1):

That precise message can come from `WCF` when authentication is set to be at message level.

To configure `SoapUI` to authenticate at message level you need to:

1. Go to projet view and select tab `WS-Security Configurations`. See image bellow.
2. Add an Outgoing configuration. Call it `username`, for example.
3. Add `WSS Entry` of type `Username`.
4. Fill username and password
5. Set password mode as text.

[image]

Now you can use it in every request. To do so, do the following:
1. Create the request. Old ones will not see the new setting.
2. Add basic authentication. Don't fill the username neither the password. See image below
3. At the Outgoing WSS combo box, select the created item `username`.

[image]

Now try it.

The reason that the service uses authentication on the message level could be because the service uses MTOM. If so, enable MTOM at the project level too.